# Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'Invoked on incorrect queue

Tags: ios, xmpp, chat, xmppframework

Working with `XMPP Framework`. Some times app crashing here is the log

```
 Assertion failure in -[XMPPIDTracker removeAllIDs], (project path)/XMPPFramework-master/Utilities/XMPPIDTracker.m:231

Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'Invoked on incorrect queue'

First throw call stack:

(0x22054c1f 0x2f7ffc8b 0x22054af5 0x22d24d7f 0x22da4d 0x2d4435 0x2d42c1 0xc346d 0xc5845 0x22d64c01 0x2201b2a7 0x2201ae23 0x22019073 0x21f67211 0x21f67023 0x293600a9 0x255731d1 0xd1959 0x2fd7faaf)

libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException
```

Comment: Did you manage to solve this issue?